# How to select top level schema in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema

I have a table `foo` on top level and a table `foo` in schema `bar`.

When using this query:

```
select  *
from bar.foo
natural join foo
where foo.baz = 'test'
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  table reference "foo" is ambiguous
LINE 4: where foo.baz = 'test'
```

I can resolve this by using an alias:

```
select  *
from bar.foo
natural join foo as f
where f.baz = 'test'
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to specifiy the top level schema directly (to make clear to SQL that I'm not talking about `bar.foo`), without using an alias? For example something like this:

```
select  *
from bar.foo
natural join foo
where .foo.baz = 'test'
```

or like this:

```
select  *
from bar.foo
natural join foo
where root_schema.foo.baz = 'test'
```

Comment: Don't use `natural join`!  Explicitly list the `join` conditions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "top-level" schema. All schemas are on the same level. There is a priority in *searching* unqualified objects, which is defined by the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

The default schema in a default installation is called `public` where all unqualified objects are created. So in your case you most probably want to use that.

As both tables have the same name, you also need to use a table alias for each of them to be able to distinguish them.

```
select  *
from bar.foo bf
  join public.foo pf on pf.id = bf.id
where bf.baz = 'test'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Replacing `root_schema` in my example above with `public` does the trick nicely :)